# How to delegate click event from parent (ViewGroup) to child (View) android?

Tags: android

You can, of course, assign onclick to all child views through a loop, but is there such an opportunity to hang the click event on the parent element, and then receive the event on the desired child view, as, for example, in html/js through the event target?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an `onClickListener()` for the parent and then inside that you can delegate the click using `child.performClick()`. if you cant to know more, you can reference https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()

The code would look something like this:

```
parent.setOnClickListener {
  child.performClick()
}
```

Comment: There are 3 buttons in the ViewGroup, by clicking on the first button it returns 1, on the second 2, on the third 3, how to do this with onClickListener only on the parent element?